How to differentiate the function given by the integral of $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$
I am trying to solve the following assignment:
Prove the the following function is differentiable with a continuous derivative twice on $\mathbb{R}$, and classify all of it’s extreme points: $$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$$
And I want to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, but the function inside isn’t defined at 0. How do I overcome this?

You can define it at $0$. We have $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$. So if you define it to be $1$ at $t=0$ then you will get a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

This is called the sine integral as the integral of the sinc function

@Mark I just did what you said, but I don't understand how can I justify going back from my newly defined function to just $\frac{\sin t}{t}$. Any chance you can make create an answer, or at least the formal beginning of it?
